# How to know if a point in a $n$ dimensional space is inside an area?

Tags: geometry

Lets say that we have a 2 dimensional space and have a point $P(x, y)$.
 If I have an area, lets say the area that is inside these points

$P_1(-1,-1);P_2(-1,1);P_3(1,-1);P_4(1,1);$

and the point $P(\frac{1}{2},\sqrt{2})$,

how can I prove that the point $P$ is inside or outside the area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by the inside the convex hull of those points, a point $P$ is in the inside of the polytope (convex hull of the points) $P_i$, $i=1,..n$, if and only if there are $\lambda_i$, $i=1,..,n$, $0 \leq \lambda_i$, $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1$ and
$$
P = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i P_i
$$
since the definition of the convex hull of those points is
$$
\{ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i P_i\ |\ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \}.
$$
However, calculating it like this is hard. There is another way computing the so called supporting hyperplanes of the polytope and its inner normals. Have a look at Ewald: Combinatorial Convexity for more about this topic.