# How to know if a point lies inside a convex hull in n dimensions *efficiently*?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hulls

I want to calculate whether a point $P$ lies a convex hull or not in high dimensions, e.g. $n = 50$.
I am aware of the linear programming approach that boils down to solve the following equation for each point $P$ and the convex hull spanning points $P_{i}$:

$P = \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \lambda _{i}P_{i}$

Unfortunately, this approach does not scale well for high dimensions.
On my search for a more efficient solution I stumbled across the following thread:
[How to know if a point in a $n$ dimensional space is inside an area?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150337/how-to-know-if-a-point-in-a-n-dimensional-space-is-inside-an-area)
Since the guidelines forbid to ask questions there I am forced to create a new thread.

The approach the user sebigu proposed is not very clear to me although I bought the recommended book and read the corresponding paragraphs. He proposed to look at the *supporting hyperplanes* and the *inner normals*. What benefit does it hold to inspect these? Let's assume the connection between two *supporting points* of the convex hull span a *supporting hyperplane* and I can construct a normal between $P$ and the *supporting hyperplane*.
What value does this add? How can I conclude from there whether $P$ lies inside the convex hull or not?

Thank you in advance

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> This isn't an answer in the sense of this site (hence the comment), but do you know of [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/), which does arbitrary-dimensional computations and is Very Likely to implement this type of test?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much!
I know about CGAL in general, but did not encounter this specific test yet.
I'll look into it and report, thank you!

Comment: Update: I looked into CGAL, but there is no method that suits my needs. Accordingly, I'll have to stick to the linear program.